# Array flip and merge multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

How do I go about making the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [r_id] => 1
            [r_rate] => 180.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [r_id] => 2
            [r_rate] => 100.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [r_id] => 3
            [r_rate] => 100.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [r_id] => 4
            [r_rate] => 100.00
        )

)
```

Look like this: (array value r_id = array key, with a value of r_rate)

```
Array
(
    [1] => 180.00 // [r_id] => [r_rate]
    [2] => 100.00
    [3] => 100.00
    [4] => 100.00

)
```

I have tried using `array_flip` and `array_merge` and looping through the array, but with very little success. The array name is `$r_id`.

Comment: `array_flip` turns the values into keys, but keys have to be strings or numbers, they can't be arrays.

Comment: `array_merge` is for combining two arrays, but you only have one array, I don't see how you expected that to help.

Comment: It would be useful if you showed the loop you tried to write, so we can explain where you went wrong and you'll learn from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a simple foreach for this purpose:

```
foreach($original_array as $values) {
    $new_array[$values['r_id']] = $values['r_rate'];
         //   ^ so the r_id assign it as key  ^ and the rate becomes the values
}
```

So finally you just get a flat array.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple loop:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($r_id as $element) {
    $result[$element['r_id']] = $element['r_rate'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that result using a native function called [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) in **PHP >= 5.5.0**.

```
$result = array_column($array, 'r_rate', 'r_id');
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/u5157